# When USB drive inserted, calling script once with knowledge of mount point

Tags: usb, ntfs, udev, fat32, exfat

Using lubuntu 16.04.

In short, I would like to have a (preferably bash) script called once upon insertion of a USB drive, with the script having access to the path name of the mount point. I have only parts of this working. I have searched online for a full solution but have not yet found one.

--

Currently, I have a rule of the following format to detect when a USB device has been inserted:

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/home/user/script.sh"
```

However, I am encountering issues:

I have not been able to figure out how to have the script know of the root directory of the mounted device. The script cannot simply look at a list of mounted USB devices, as there already may be one or more other USB drives already mounted.

I also have noticed that the script is called multiple times (10-20 in my testing) during the mount process, only the last call of which has the device accessible (mount shows device as rw). This appears to happen both with a native Linux installation and a VirtualBox VM.

I need this to work for FAT32, exFAT, and NTFS file systems. (FAT32 drives appear to be mounted at /media/usb*number*.  exFAT and NTFS drives appear to be mounted at /media/*user*/*drivelabel*. (I have not yet tested what happens if two drives have the same label).

When I have inserted a USB drive, I have seen  the popup window 'Removable medium is inserted. Please select the action you want to perform: o *Open in File Manager*'. When I select OK, the file manager opens with the USB drive path. Essentially I want to have a script automatically called in this instance, having access to this path name.

Comment: It's the same usb or could be any?

Comment: I am trying to check for the existence of a file on the just-mounted USB drive and perform an action on that file if its there.  The file may already exist on another mounted USB drive but I do not want the action to happen on that existing file.